# What is the difference in using AWS Public DNS instead of Public IP or the vise versa

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

What is the difference in using AWS Public DNS instead of Public IP or the vise versa. 
Both typing in the browser gives me the same result.

If both are going to give me the same result why there are two options.

When we stop the EC2 instance and start both DNS and IP gets changed. Is there any other to have one constant link to access my website.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation which spells this out quite clearly: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is when you want to create another DNS entry on this one.

If you want CNAME, use Public DNS.
If you want A records, use Public IP.

In some case, you have to use an A record, for instance when you want to point your root domain at it :

> example.com have to be an A record
>
> www.example.com can be a CNAME.

If you want to have a constant link to your website, you can either use an [EIP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) (elastic IP) or an [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/?nc1=h_ls) (Elastic Load Balancer).
Check the AWS doc :

The EIP is free when you use it (when the instance is running).

The ELB is around 25$ a month but is much more usefull.

You can use it to terminate HTTPS connection, or for port forwarding (the link point on port 80 and is forwaded to 8080 or whatever you are using.

Comment: Is there any free option so that I can use it